# Ubuntu doesn't recognise my external monitor

Tags: screen, monitor

I was trying to plug in an external monitor (Dell U2312HM) in my Dell XPS 15 laptop, but all I see is a black screen (on the external monitor, my normal screen is fine). When I open Settings, it shows no sign of the monitor whatsoever. Pressing 'Detect Displays' does nothing. Does anyone have a clue of what's going on here?

I'm a bit of a newbie, so if you want more information, please ask.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `lspci |grep vga`. What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an owner of a Dell XPS 15 laptop (L501X to be precise). It comes with a Nvidia GeForce 420M (or later) graphics card, so if you have the NVidia drivers installed & activated, try the **NVidia X Server Settings** program to detect your new display.

Type `nvidia` in the dash to find it. Then click on `Detect Displays` in the `X Server Display Configuration` menu. See:

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! However, typing `nvidia` in the dash gives 0 results. Any idea of what to do next?

Comment: Okay, I got the program running, but instead of one big screen (like in your case) I've got three: X screen 0 (which is my laptop screen), CRT-0 (it says 'Disabled') and DFP-0 ('Disabled'). Clicking 'detect displays' does nothing. Do you want a printscreen of that?

Also, I connect the screen to my laptop with a HDMI cable. Might that be the problem?